# Powershell - printing out during a loop

Tags: powershell, scripting, active-directory

I have to go through an OU and remove all the memberOf groups for all users.  The script I have works, but I cannot get it to print out when each user is processed.  So when I run the script, it working, but nothing happens until its complete.  For piece of mind, I want to SEE the current login name that is being processed, but I can't, for the life of me, get the write-host command to write to my screen.

Here is my code:

```
$users = get-aduser -filter * -searchbase "ou=disabled,dc=corp,dc=test,dc=org" | Sort-Object -Property Name

Function removeMemberShips {
    Param( [string] $SAMAccountName)

    $user = get-aduser $SAMAccountName -properties memberof

    $userGroups = $user.memberof
    $userGroups | %{get-adgroup $_ | Remove-ADGroupMember -confirm:$false -member $SAMAccountName}
    $userGroups = $null
}
$users | %{removeMemberShips $_.SAMAccountName}
```

Comment: Tried what was suggested below as well as placing a write-host command in just about every place I could in the method, outside.  What I think would work, which is what is posted below, just doesn't output to the screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most obvious way seems to be:

```
$users | %{
    removeMemberShips $_.SAMAccountName
    Write-Host $_.SAMAccountName
}
```

Comment: Doesn't write to the screen.  If I remove the RemoveMemverships method, it will obviously print out the samaccountname of each user, but somehow, its not playing nicely with the method.